# How to launch setInterval with parameters and multiple functions

Tags: animation, arguments, parameter-passing, setinterval

I am new to javascript. I am trying to draw a pacman that opens and closes its mouth passing a drawing function with arguments to a callback setInterval.

Althoug the question has been posed several times, the implementations did not work with me -- for instance `setInterval( function() { funca(parms); }, delay );` or `setInterval(funca, delay, parms);`.

If I get it properly, I need a function to draw an object and another to clear the screen. Thus, I need to launch two functions in sequence.

How can I do that (properly)?

Thank you

Here is the code I wrote:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PacMan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="grid.js"></script>
    <script src="pacman.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Animated PacMan</h1>
    <canvas id="grid" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var context = document.getElementById("grid").getContext("2d");
      context.strokeStyle = "white";
      context.lineWidth = 1.5;
      var x= 0, y = context.canvas.height/2;
      var z = 0.8;
      //draw_pacman(context, context.canvas.width/2, y, 100, z); ## this works ##
      setInterval(draw_pacman, 1.0, context, context.canvas.width / 2, y, 100, update(z));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

with pacman.js:

```
function draw_pacman(ctx, x_crd, y_crd, radius, mouth) {
  angle = 0.2 * Math.PI * mouth;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x_crd, y_crd, radius, angle, -angle);
  ctx.lineTo(x_crd, y_crd);
  ctx.closePath()
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}
function update(x) {
  x += 1;
}
function frame(ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  draw(ctx);
  update();
}
```